# Open a file in Visual Studio's CSS Source Editor

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, less, dotless

I am using [Phil Haack's T4CSS T4 template](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/02/t4-template-for-less-css.aspx) based on [.less](http://www.dotlesscss.com/)

One bad thing about Phil's solution is that visual studio opens the .less files as plain text files rather than as css files. (Thus no intellisense.)

How can I get VS to open a .less file in the CSS Source Editor?

I've tried:

1. Right Click > Open With, but the CSS Source Editor isn't listed.
2. Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extensions, but once again, CSS Source Editor isn't listed.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Midscape's Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) Visual Studio Extension adds support for .less files, including syntax highlighting and Intellisense.  It also adds support for SASS and CoffeeScript.

Comment: After a week or so of using this, I have uninstalled it due to:
(a) annoying nagging adverts telling you to upgrade and (b) a weird bug that stopped me being able to save my .less files intermittently

Comment: Similar to @Hainesy I uninstalled it as I found it very clunky.

Answer (score 26):

I just posted an extension that does this; you can [download it from the Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dd5635b0-3c70-484f-abcb-cbdcabaa9923).

The key to the extension is the `.pkgdef` file:

```
[$RootKey$\Languages\File Extensions\.less]
@="{A764E898-518D-11d2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}"

[$RootKey$\Editors\{A764E89A-518D-11d2-9A89-00C04F79EFC3}\Extensions]
"less"=dword:00000028
```

Note that this extension doesn't do anything to help the CSS language service support Less; nested rules, for example, don't work very well at all (it confuses the CSS language service).

Comment: Is there any way to get the CSS validation engine going on .less files?

Comment: @Chris Tools->Options->Text editor->CSS->Miscellaneous->untick 'Detect errors' might do the trick.

Comment: Any way of getting a VS2008-compatible version?

Comment: You should be able to set the equivalent reg keys for VS2008; all the extension does is load the .pkgdef file, which is essentially just a .reg file that evaluates properties like $RootKey$.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the dotless.Compiler.exe tool (as opposed to the http handler), there is nothing to say your files have to end with .less. I name my suffix my .less files with .css so that Visual Studio treats them like css files. E.g. my naming convention is:

/css/common.less.css ==> /css/common.css

I run the dotLess compiler as a post-build event, e.g.

```
$(SolutionDir)\packages\dotless.1.1.0\Tools\dotless.Compiler.exe "$(ProjectDir)\css\common.less.css" "$(ProjectDir)\css\common.css"
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to turn on Visual Studio 2010 .css Intellisense on .less file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973604/how-to-turn-on-visual-studio-2010-css-intellisense-on-less-file)