# Can I tell Visual Studio how treat a file with a custom file extension?

Tags: visual-studio, file-extension

Can I tell Visual Studio how treat a file with a custom file extension? I want to be able to open a file with ".xxx" extension in Visual Studio and have CSS highlighting.

I've tried to do it by going to VS -> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension but in the Editor drop down there is nothing to specify "treat it as CSS".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a file in Visual Studio's CSS Source Editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346243/open-a-file-in-visual-studios-css-source-editor)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In Visual Studio go to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension`

There you can add specific extensions and choose which 'Editor' Visual Studio uses for that extension.

Comment: I know this answer came super late, but I think anyone searching for this will end up here, and it's now far simpler than it apparently used to be.

Comment: There is no CSS option in `Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension` Editor dropdown.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, there is a CSS Editor in the list.

Comment: When using this method, VS pops-up a dialog with an input box for extension name and a drop-down for language (ex: C#, JavaScript). It doesn't matter if you use a period/dot before the extension because VS understands it both ways.

Answer (score 6):

For recent versions of Visual Studio, see [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34799783/2688), there's a settings dialog for assigning a file extension to an editor.

### For Visual Studio 2010 and Older

There is a registry hack that you can use. https://engagesoftware.com/news/post/395/editing-sqldataprovider-scripts-within-visual-studio

Basically, you look at `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Languages\File Extensions\.css` (changing the version number based on your version of VS, and removing `Wow6432Node` if you aren't on a 64-bit OS) and make a copy of that, calling it `.my-custom-extension`

**UPDATE**  According to [a similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346243/open-a-file-in-visual-studios-css-source-editor), for some extensions (i.e. CSS), there's another step to be taken.  It says to take the GUID from the extension that you're copying, and find its entry in `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Editors` and add a DWORD value in its `Extensions` key like the existing `css` value.  That question also points to an extension in the VS gallery that does that.  However, even after doing that, I'm still unable to get syntax highlighting, myself...

Comment: I went to the path in regedit, made a copy of '.css' key and renamed it to '.less'. Restarted my PC, opened '.less' file in VS but still no CSS highlighting. What else could I be missing?

Comment: I dunno.  I'm seeing the same thing (that it works fine for `.SQL` but not for `.CSS`...)

Comment: BTW, just closing Visual Studio is enough for changes to take effect, don't need to restart your machine.

Comment: there is also an VS extension that does this for you. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahric/archive/2010/03/01/new-extension-css-is-less.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Tested on Visual Studio 2019. 
**Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension**
add your file extension with '.' like .ejs (Node.JS View Engine) and then set it to one of known editors and press add:
.ejs >> HTML Editor 
Close and reopen the files with .ejs in VS & you will see HTML markups on them.

Answer (score 0):

I originally posted this answer [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-open-custom-file-types-anymore/10138704#T-N10439731) but I feel it is worth repeating.

The **Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension** route seems to only let your select from a fix set of editor. Right?

I noticed (quite by chance) that there is an **Open With** option on the context menu when you right click:

[image]

You can then add a bespoke application (like appTranslator Pro) and set it as default:

[image]

Now I can double-click the APT file and it will automatically open in appTranslator Pro. No more popup warnings!