# tpp file - Debugging info not displayed and no colors in the file like in a cpp file

Tags: visual-studio

I currently have a tpp file ,  the code just works fine however there is no color in the tpp file. The font color is simply black and nothing like the colors in a cpp file. Also when the code is running and after hitting a breakpoint the value of variables (debug) are not displayed. Any suggestions why ? I am using VS2010

Comment: What is a tpp file and how are you using it?  This may help with the syntax highlighting issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493690/can-i-tell-visual-studio-how-treat-a-file-with-a-custom-file-extension  I haven't tried it myself, I just stick to what it already recognizes.

Comment: Get rid of the ancient c++ tpp extension if you can - rename the file to be cpp. Otherwise you'd need VS custom file type handler.