# After setting up IIS Express to recognize JSON file type - Can VS invoke a better editor other than plain text?

Tags: javascript, json, iis, express, visual-studio-2013

I've setup IIS Express to handle a .json filetype as discussed in this stackoverflow posting [Allow loading of JSON files in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516829/allow-loading-of-json-files-in-visual-studio-express-2013-for-web)

Once I did that VS now loads the .json file as a plain text file.  Before it would edit it as a javascript file, which while not perfect, at least gave some syntax checks (except for showing some errors that were legal JSON).  Is there a way to setup VS Express for Web 2013 to edit JSON files with syntax checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can choose an editor by doing a right click on the file in the Solution Explorer, selecting `Open with...`, trying to find something that looks more appropriate. Then you can do `Set as default` there.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be a little complicated. I tried [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/08/22/using-custom-file-extension-associations-vstipenv0038.aspx), but there is no javascript option in the list. So probably you'll have to go through this: [Can I tell Visual Studio how treat a file with a custom file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493690/can-i-tell-visual-studio-how-treat-a-file-with-a-custom-file-extension)