# VS IDE: Per-solution association of custom file extensions to specific programming languages ("Editing Experience")

Tags: visual-studio

In MS Visual Studio (e.g., 2022), there is a method to associate custom extensions to programming languages ("Editing Experience"), allowing to have code highlighting and related convenience in such files. It is explained in [Can I tell Visual Studio how treat a file with a custom file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493690/can-i-tell-visual-studio-how-treat-a-file-with-a-custom-file-extension;) and also in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-file-extension.

However, I can't find an option to do that per-solution (or per-project) there. In a specific project, there may be some convention about custom extensions (say, for generated files), which may be irrelevant for other projects (and even potentially conflict with other projects). Is there a way to do that, that I possibly overlooked?

Thanks!