# Javascript Intellisense in CSHTML file when using MVC Bundling

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, intellisense, visual-studio-2013

I am using MVC4 with Razor in VS 2013 RC. I want to use Javascript intellisense from a cshtml view for Javascript that has been included in my _layout file through a Bundle.

Intellisense is not working. Is it because I'm using bundling? Any advice on troubleshooting?

There is a similar question to mine ([Intellisense with MVC4 Style Bundling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717750/intellisense-with-mvc4-style-bundling)). But at that time no one provided an answer.

Btw, the file is in my _reference.js file:

```
/// <reference path="../entities/analyticsentities.js" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason adding these files to the _reference.js file doesn't seem to make the file available to Intellisense. I'm not sure if I'm not understanding how the feature works, or if this is a bug.

However, adding the reference directly to the top of the Javascript file I'm working with gives me Intellisense just fine.

For example, I have added the below to the top of each Javascript file from which I want Intellisense on the JayData library:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../scripts/jaydata.js" />
```