# Intellisense for .less file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, less

I am following Luke's solution for this problem, it has been asked in stack overflow [How to turn on Visual Studio 2010 .css Intellisense on .less file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973604/how-to-turn-on-visual-studio-2010-css-intellisense-on-less-file)

but still no luck, same plain text, Am I missing something by only installing the extension in visual studio 2010 ?? Should I do something else??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, actually when I restarted visual studio, it worked with an initial warning - *"visual studio has encountered a problem because of extension"*, after that it worked normally, hope it's not an issue. I was silly, I should have try this before asking on stack. May be if somebody else will face the same problem, at least he would save his time by looking at this.